# Fetch Project Users from BIM360 using Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I was able to retrieve Project Users of a project in BIM 360 using Forge API about a month back, using API as GET - https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users.
Since the last month, I am not able to fetch the users and receiving 403 responses. I have tried with the two-legged and three-legged token, as well as appending the header of the region in request, but still not getting the response.
API Link: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/
Please assist me, if anyone is aware of any changes made in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this request and I got this 403 response.

```
{
  "developerMessage": "Token does not have the privilege for this request.",
  "moreInfo":"https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/", 
  "errorCode": "AUTH-010"
}
```

As we can read, I was missing `account:read` in the scope. Can you check that or give us the `developerMessage` you receive ?

Comment: AlexAR-  Yes, i have given, acccount: read scope while fetching the token and following is the response I am receving as: {
    "status": 403,
    "type": "",
    "id": "fa6d6fbd45f9c6f2",
    "title": "Forbidden",
    "detail": "The 2 legged clientId does not have access"
} and same applies for three legged toke. It was working fine about a month back and suddenly it starts showing this issue.

Comment: The message `The client_id specified does not have access to the api products` is returned when your Forge App does not have access to the BIM360 project (not added in the custom integration part). Can you check that ? Do you have the same problem when doing different type of BIM360 requests with the same `Forge Client ID`?

Comment: I am able to fetch custom attributes parameters, path, and location of all files within each project, which is coming fine, but users' information is showing this issue. The user API is showing as a beta on the Autodesk site, so, is there a possibility of its instability. https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users.

Comment: Hey, could you please, ensure the user (User-Id header or 3LO) have required permission? 
Please, refer to https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/#headers